# I'm unable to upload files to my Jupyter Notebook on Google Colab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

On the Files tab on the left I click the Upload button to upload a file called `titanic_train.csv`. However, the image goes to the *bottom* of the files tab and just stays there, never becoming accessible to my programs,

[image: titanic_train.png never uploads]

As a workaround, I also tried uploading via Google Colab's built-in `google.colab.files.upload` method, which successfully prompts me for a file, but then stalls at 0% uploaded with the message:

```
titanic_train.csv(text/csv) - 72499 bytes, last modified: 9/20/2018 - 0% done
```

Viz,

[image: The upload stalls at 0 percent]

Does anyone have an idea of what I may be doing wrong, or how I could resolve this so my programs can successfully access files via Google Colab?

I'm doing this with Chrome on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the permissions on my file. It's the famous Titanic Survivor dataset, which I downloaded from Kaggle. The file came with a permission of No Read, No Write, No Execute:

```
me@fakehost:~/titanic-dataset$ ls -l
total 116
---------- 1 hc-16 hc-16  2843 sep 20  2018 gender_baseline.csv
---------- 1 hc-16 hc-16 39299 sep 20  2018 titanic_test.csv
---------- 1 hc-16 hc-16 72499 sep 20  2018 titanic_train.csv
```

Chrome can't upload the file because it has no read access, so this is fixed as easy as `chmod 400 *`

Huge relief, I can't imagine why Kaggle gives these files a permission of `000` to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Using safari caused some issues when I tried uploading, did you try Chrome? That worked for me. Also try uploading with this code. This one also lets you save the file, so you don't have to upload it every 12 hours.

```py
def upload_files():
  from google.colab import files
  uploaded = files.upload()
  for k, v in uploaded.items():
    open(k, 'wb').write(v)
  return list(uploaded.keys())

upload_files()
```

Comment: I'm using Chrome on Ubuntu 16.04, issue sadly ongoing. Thanks for the tip about saving the file, though!